# add two responsive tinynav menus

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I have two menus in my website and want to make them responsive, my original menu looks like this:

```
<nav class="main-menu left" id="nav">  
    <div class="menu-left-main-menu-container">
        <ul id="menu-left-main-menu">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about-us.html">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="menu.html">Menus</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>                                                                                      
</nav>

<div class="clear"></div>

<nav class="main-menu right" id="nav2">                    
    <div class="menu-right-main-menu-container">
        <ul class="clearfix" id="menu-right-main-menu">
             <li><a href="branch.html">Branches</a></li>
             <li><a href="contact.html">Jobs</a></li>
             <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>                 
</nav>
```

I use the tinyNav plugin to make my menus responsive:

```
$('#nav ul').tinyNav({active: 'current-menu-item'});    
var text_menu = $("#tinynav1 option:selected").text();
$(".mobile-menu").html(text_menu);
```

I have another menu with id `id="nav2"`, how can add a second menu using tinyNav

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just add a second selector and call `tinyNav` again?

`$('#nav2 ul').tinyNav({active: 'current-menu-item'});`

Comment: i try this way but menu not appear and make problem in my site

Comment: Do you have a link to an example of what you're talking about?

Comment: link :- www.kamgfx.com/demo